# Show that $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{|f(z)|^2}{z^{n-1}}dz=a_{0}a_{n}R^{2n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{|f(z)|^2}{z^{n-1}}dz=a_{0}a_{n}R^{2n}$. Where $f(z)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+...+a_{n}z^{n},n\geq 0$

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a complex conjugate, and you should have multiply by $z^{n-1}$ rather than divide by it (or the denominator should be $z^{n+1}$ but then $R$ wouldn't appear on the RHS).

Note that $\bar{z}=\dfrac{R^2}{z}$ when $|z|=R$ so
$$
\overline{f(z)}=\overline{a_0}+\overline{a_1}\frac{R^2}{z}+\dots+\overline{a_n}\frac{R^{2n}}{z^n}.
$$
Thus you can rewrite the integrand as a meromorphic function and read off the answer as the coefficient of $z^n$ (if the integrand was $\dfrac{|f(z)|^2}{z^{n+1}}$) $=\overline{a_0}a_n$, or the coefficient of $z^{-n}$ (if the integrand was $z^{n-1}|f(z)|^2$) $=a_0\overline{a_n}R^{2n}$.